# What is "probity"?

Tags: legal-terms

I have found a number of definitions but none are satisfyingly congruent with the usages that I have seen in legal contexts including several times on here, which generally use it to describe a quality of evidence, even the definitions which I have found through search engines in specifically legal dictionaries.

Comment: I suppose I'm looking for a more in depth explanation of the concept than a simple dictionary definition. I think this different level of scope is implied by the medium of being asked as a question on this site, and I suppose an answer could also include explanation of the peculiarities of the legal usage compared with other usages etc., as well as typical/conventional legal usage contexts. Generally legal concepts are explained by example scenarios in which they may be applied rather than simple dictionary definitions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The definitions you found online and in legal dictionaries are likely correct. I suspect you found something such as:

> The quality or condition of having strong moral principles; integrity, good character; honesty, decency. (Oxford English Dictionary)

This is the definition corresponding to the most typical (what many would call the "correct") use of the word. It is often used in phrases like "[probity and fair dealing](https://www.canlii.org/en/#search/text=probity)."

If you have seen other uses, in relation to the quality of evidence, this is an occasional *misuse*. See Footnote 54 in Matthew Gourlay, et al., [*Modern Criminal Evidence*, Chapter 1](https://emond.ca/Emond/media/Sample-chapters/MCE_01_2nd.pdf):

> There is an unfortunate trend in some recent judicial decisions of using the term "probity" as a synonym for probative value: see e.g. *R v Durham Regional Crime Stoppers Inc*, 2017 SCC 45, [2017] 2 SCR 157 at paras 43-47. "Probity" refers to moral uprightness and is not the noun form of the adjective "probative." If a new coinage is required, "probativity" would be preferable.